# AWS Database Migration Services endpoint errors

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to setup a source MSSQL endpoint and a target MYSQL endpoint, each exist in the same vpc as the replication instance setup but I receive

> Operation:testEndpointDetails:[errType=ERROR_RESPONSE, status=122502, errMessage=Failed to connect [122502] ODBC general error., errDetails= RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: HY000 NativeError: 15 Message: [unixODBC][Simba][SqlServerODBC] (15) Failed to connect to the SQL Server instance: [HY000]: Connection broken [122502] ODBC general error.]

for the MSSQL source test.

and

> Operation:testEndpointDetails:[errType=ERROR_RESPONSE, status=122502, errMessage=Cannot connect to ODBC provider [122502] ODBC general error., errDetails= RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: HY000 NativeError: 2003 Message: [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql_endpoint' (110) [122502] ODBC general error.]

for the MYSQL target test.

I've reentered in the credentials numerous times setting the server name for both the source and target to the subsequent RDS endpoints of each instance as well as their corresponding login credentials, ports etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to check is your security groups to ensure that both systems can talk to each other. It's not enough for them to reside in the same VPC. If you have ec2 instances that use the source, you could possibly use this as the security group.

Answer (score 2):

The above suggestion from John Paul Hayes was correct, security group on both RDS instances was changed from a custom one setup to the default AWS one.